# .slideToggle (using Jquery) not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a header that I built using HTML, CSS, and Bootstrap. Using `.slideToggle()` from JQuery, I want to add a sliding panel to it.

**For reference: all of my code is below +** [**screenshot of header (panel hidden)**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3l61.jpg) + [**screenshot of header (panel shown)**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Bu6x.jpg)

Basically, I would like to click on `#products` to make `#panel-products` (hidden with `display: none;`) appear and slide down. When clicking on `#products` again, `#panel-products` should slide back up and disappear. However, none of this is happening. I've read on other sites that when using `.slideToggle()`, it detects for hidden elements and acts accordingly.

My HTML:

```
<HTML>
<head>
    <title>Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Bootstrap(files)/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Reproduce.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JQuery(files)/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Reproduce.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1 class="col-sm-4">WEBSITE</h1>
        <nav class="col-sm-8">
            <a><span id="login">Login</span></a>
            <a><span id="join">Join</span></a>
            <a><span id="products">Products</span><br>
                <span id="panel-products">
                    <span id="computers">Computers</span><br>
                    <span id="tablets">Tablets</span><br>
                    <span id="phones">Phones</span>
                </span>
            </a>
            <a><span id="about">About</span></a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
</body>
</HTML>
```

My CSS:

```
header .row {
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
}

header h1 {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

header nav {
    font-size: 18px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

header nav > a {
    margin-top: 13px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

header #panel-products {
    font-size: x-small;
    display: none;
}
```

My JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    $("#products").click(function () {
        $("#panel-products").slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: its working. here's your [code](https://jsfiddle.net/kydh24cL/)

Comment: Press F12 and check console, if you have something like: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" there.. you didn't included jQuery properly (check paths)...

Comment: @sinisake By "paths" do you mean the content inside the `src=" "` attribute in my `<script>` element within the head my HTML document? If so, I checked and that was it. Did not specify  `src=" "` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This Bootstrap demo uses:

- `.navbar-right` instead of `justify-content:flex-end`
- `data-toggle="dropdown"` instead of `.slideToggle()`
- `glyphicon` instead of entities and gifs.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Website</title>
<link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<style>

</style>
</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSite</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a id='products' class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Products
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul id='product-panel' class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-console"></span> Computer</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-blackboard"></span> Tablet</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span> Phone</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      </ul>
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
       <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script> 
<script>


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

View Snippet in full page mode then resize window or view with Developer Tools <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>.